# Qualtrics DropDown Menu Highlight CSS

Tags: css, dropdown, qualtrics

I am trying to change the hover color on a Qualtrics Drop Down (Multiple Choice) question. Currently it is defaulting to a blue color, but I need the hover to be a gold color.

This is the CSS I am using, but it is just making the whole drop down list the color ('Selection' is the class name for all the drop down options so it makes sense).

```
.Skin .MC .ChoiceStructure .Selection {
    background-color: #######;
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Do I need to use Javascript to assign classes to the individual options? Or does anyone know the class name for the individual answer options?

Comment: can you post your html? you can not use :hover to do it?

Comment: Here is the HTML for that particular question. I have a few dropdown throughout the Qualtrics survey. That is just a piece of the code (it is too long to post all of it).

Comment: <select class="ChoiceStructure Selection QR-QID29 QWatchTimer" name="QR~QID29" id="QR~QID29" data-runtime-value="runtime.Selected"> 
<option aria-label="Blank" value="QR~QID29~null"></option>  
 <option class="Selection" value="1" id="QR~QID29~1">Aria</option>

Comment: :hover does not work